# AttributeError with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I am trying to make a cx_Freeze gui in python 3.

When I type `pyton setup.py build`

I get this error :

```
running build
running build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 356, in <module>
    executables=executables
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py",
n setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in s
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in r

    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in r
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line

    self.run_command(cmd_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in ru
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in r
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py",
n run
    zipExcludePackages = self.zip_exclude_packages)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py
, in __init__
    self._VerifyConfiguration()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\freezer.py
, in _VerifyConfiguration
    executable._VerifyConfiguration(self)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_VerifyConfiguration'
```

My code is to long to be copied here but it is in two parts

- The tkinter class (the 'long' part)
- The simple cx_Freeze script

**EDIT**
The line where the error is is the last line of the `setup` function:

```
setup(
    name=inter.name,
    version=inter.version,
    description=inter.description,
    author=inter.author,
    options={"build_exe": options},
    executables=executables
    )
```

Comment: At least post the code around line 356 of setup.py, where the error originates.

Comment: This is the last line of the `setup` function : `executables=executables`